# Sound Issues on a Macbook Air 4.2

Tags: sound

Good morning to all.Im new on ths community and i was having problems with the sound quality of my macbook air 4.2 with ubuntu.Alsa mixer doesnt show me surround option.I NEED SOME HELP PLEASE.

[image: Alsamixer Gui doesnt show surround tab]

Comment: Please edit the question and add information about which Ubuntu version you are using

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec`?

Comment: Codec: Cirrus Logic CS4206
Codec: Intel PantherPoint HDMI

Comment: Let me know if my answer works. In case you don't know how to modify a system file (you will have to use sudo), please let me know, I am happy to provide detailed steps.

Answer (score 0):

Create the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` (in case it exists, replace it with the following contents), with the following contents

```
options snd-hda-intel model=mba42
```

The first command takes a backup of the file, if it exists, and the second command adds content.

```
sudo mv /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf.bkup

echo 'options snd-hda-intel model=mba42' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Reboot.

Comment: im receiving an dennid permission trying to input /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

Comment: @ArkitekterGroup You will need sudo to modify system files. Try the new commands

Comment: Did the new commands in the edited answer work?

Comment: Nope.I was wrong with the macbook model its a Macbook Air 5.1.Im keep having that problem the audio sounds like cracked and mono at the same time.